# Не проводит тест unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

столкнулся с проблемой, при запуске теста своего кода, ничего не происходит

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    """Строит отформатированное полное имя"""
    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    return full_name.title()
```

Код теста:

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name


class NameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Тесты для name_function.py"""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        """Имена вида 'Janis Joplin' работают правильно?"""
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')


unittest.main()
```

[image: Вот какой результат мне выдаёт тест]

Comment: Судя по всему, Ваш тест вовсе не запускается; в противном случае в консоли было `Ran 1 tests in ...s`, а не `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`

Comment: @4500zenja А в чём причина? Не могу понять :( Использую PyCharm на OC win10

Comment: @insolor Не даёт результат, при прогоне через дебаггер показывает Ran 1 test in 1.349s

Comment: Если Run 1 test, значит тест выполнился.

Comment: @insolor Я понимаю, но как мне сделать этот Ran 1 test in ...sec без дебаггера?

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что нужно сделать - обернуть вызов `unittest.main()` в конструкцию `if __name__ == "__main__":`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Тесты обычно вызываются не запуском модуля, а из модуля unittest (или pytest, в данном случае не важно), в таких случаях нужно, чтобы вызов `unittest.main()` при импорте не срабатывал, для этого и нужна конструкция `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Далее, допустим тест лежит в файле `test.py`, тестируемый модуль `name_function.py` лежит рядом в той же директории.

> Ниже все тестировалось на Linux, под Windows все то же самое должно
> работать, только пишите python вместо python3.

Пробуем запустить тесты через командную строку:

```
❯ python3 test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Через модуль unittest:

```
❯ python3 -m unittest -v test
test_first_last_name (test.NameTestCase)
Имена вида 'Janis Joplin' работают правильно? ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

При таком способе вызова, если `unittest.main()` не обернут в `if __name__ == "__main__":`, будет ошибка `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'test'`

Аналогично будет работать и без указания имени модуля, т.е. `python3 -m unittest -v` (unittest в данном случае сам найдет тестовый класс).

Через pytest (тестовый класс правда пришлось переименовать, так чтобы его имя начиналось с `Test` (например, `TestCaseName`), чтобы pytest его увидел):

```
❯ pytest -v test.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.0.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/username/Projects/uuuuu
plugins: asyncio-0.14.0, timeout-1.4.2
collected 1 item                                                               

test.py::TestCaseName::test_first_last_name PASSED                       [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.02s ===============================
```

Для отображения docstring из тестового класса и методов при запуске через pytest можно использовать решение отсюда (копировать сюда не буду, чтобы не загромождать ответ):
[Use docstrings to list tests in py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39035226/4752653)

Через PyCharm - добавляем конфигурацию запуска Unittests, Target - Custom, без параметров (в данном случае unittest сам все найдет):

[image: Скриншот конфигурации]

Запускаем (внизу в консоли теста стоит галка "Show Passed", т.е. отображать успешно пройденные тесты, по умолчанию это отключено):

[image: Результат]